# UISwitch duplicating/weird overlay in CollectionViewCells when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiswitch

I have programmatically created UISwitches in collection cells and as scrolling happens these switches are added over and over again, which is causing the half toggles (guessing is because another UISwitch is right beneath it).

This is the entire block of how the UISwitch is created.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FlagCell", for: indexPath)

    let switchOnOff = UISwitch()

    switchOnOff.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    switchOnOff.setOn(true, animated: true)

    cell.contentView.addSubview(switchOnOff)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: switchOnOff, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -10).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: switchOnOff, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true

    return cell
}
```

I was able to do this via Storyboard, but perhaps you guys may have a solution doing it programmatically.

Comment: You should not be adding subviews in `cellForItemAt`. Create a custom cell class with a switch in it.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy! I was able to get this to work. Do you mind providing a brief explanation of it?

Answer (score 0):

As rmaddy suggested, creating a custom cell class solved it.

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FlagCell
```

And move all the subviews being added in that class.